# Detect events of the presenter tool similar to onmousedown?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

In the browser it is possible to catch mouse events by adding 'onclicked'-listener functions to the corresponding div. Now I want to listen to the presenter events. By presenter I am referring to the hardware tool often used in oral presentations.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I don't understand what you want.

Comment: What do you mean by elaborate? I need to find out which event occurs by hitting the presenter keys. I have no idea how to elaborate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view of javascript is a bit misguided. Javascript is not a low-level language, it uses many abstractions, so browser's JS engines in general will not give you a direct access to the hardware, and so it's not possible for your script to identify what exactly the user is using to control web page.

I would look into onkeypress event, as most probably those remote controls that you mentioned simply simulate specific keys. I'm not familiar with those devices but I would presume they can be configured through drivers.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

You can find out if it is true with something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(ev) { console.log(ev.keyCode); });
```

And then try to use the "presenter" on the webpage.

Comment: `window.addEventListener( 'keydown', e=>{
  if(e.key === 'PageDown'||e.key === 'PageUp')console.log('presenter clicked');
});`